# Android cannot add children to a custom Layout (inherit from ViewGroup)

Tags: android, layout, view, children, viewgroup

hi I'm pretty new to android developing and I'm trying to create my own custom layout:

```
public class EqLayout extends ViewGroup {

public EqLayout(Context context){
    super(context);
}

public EqLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
}

public EqLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defstyle){
    super(context, attrs, defstyle);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int lato = getLato();
    int w = getMeasuredWidth()/lato;
    int h = getMeasuredHeight()/lato;
    int ws = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(w, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    int hs = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(h, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

    for(int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++){
        View v = getChildAt(i);
        v.measure(ws, hs);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    int lato = getLato();
    int w = (r - l)/lato;
    int h = (t - b)/lato;

    for(int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++){
        View v = getChildAt(i);
        int x = i%lato, y = i/lato;
        v.layout(x*w, y*h, (x+1)*w, (y+1)*h);
    }

}

private int getLato(){
    int r = (int) Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(getChildCount()));
    r = (r > 0) ? r : r+1;
    return r;
    }
  }
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    EqLayout eql = (EqLayout) findViewById(R.id.eqlviewlayout);
    for(int i = 0; i < 14; i++){
        Button b = new Button(this);
        b.setText("#"+i);
        eql.addView(b);
    }
    }
}
```

and that's the xml:

[image: XML file]

All seems to works fine but I cannot add a child to it.
I tried on runtime and from Android Studio by drag and drop a button but without success.

Anybody knows why that happens ? Thanks for you time, ask if you need any more info.

Comment: what is the output of `adb shell dumpsys activity top`?

Comment: how do i obtain that info ?

Comment: by running the command `adb shell dumpsys activity top` on the terminal window

Comment: http://pastebin.com/95avfSzH

Comment: strange, did you run it while your app was running?

Comment: ok nevermind, try running `hierarchyviewer` instead and see your custom `ViewGroup` and its children

Comment: thats what i get: http://imgur.com/ff96htR

Comment: its empty: no view tree at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a negative height for your children.

Just replace in your onLayout this line:

```
int h = (t - b)/lato;
```

with

```
int h = (b - t)/lato;
```

and you're good!

[image: Screenshot]